# Adding Nested Grouping Sections in the UI for Actions within a Controller

Tags: c#, swagger, swashbuckle

Is it possible to have subsections within an action grouping? We currently use Controller-based differentiation to group functions, but are hosting a large amount of controllers and could use further nesting.

In other words, I know actions can be grouped/ordered with the following, but can they be grouped multiple times:

c.GroupActionsBy(apiDesc => apiDesc.HttpMethod.ToString());
  c.OrderActionGroupsBy(new DescendingAlphabeticComparer());

Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In theory yes, we can group actions multiple times we can create an insanity of nested groups, swagger & swashbuckle are both open-source if is not implemented we can do it ourselves, but my guess is that it will take a lot of time.

My recommendation: upgrade to the latest swagger-ui 3.x, the latest version has a filter that doubles down as a search, take a look at my latest:

http://swashbuckletest.azurewebsites.net/swagger/ui/index
http://swashbuckletest.azurewebsites.net/swagger/ui/index?filter=Test

I have not published my version to Nuget yet, if you want to try it is here:
https://www.myget.org/feed/heldersepu/package/nuget/Swagger-Net